# Open model/dialog/VF Page/LWC Component from Salesforce trigger

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, javascript, dynamic-visualforce

Can we open model/dialog/alert/VF Page/Lighting component which is having yes/no button and a label  from the Salesforce trigger?

I want to show a confirmation box with yes/no button from the trigger. If user clicks "OK" trigger will execute otherwise not.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do this. Triggers are backend functionality only and may execute in contexts that have no associated user interface session

You must implement this type of functionality on the front end (Lightning, Visualforce) *before* initiating a DML operation. Be aware however that you cannot inject this functionality into standard Salesforce record pages. Anything you want to gate behind a confirmation has to be built in custom code.

Comment: Can we invoke a screenflow from the apex trigger?

Comment: No, you cannot start any UI functionality from a trigger, full stop.

Comment: Thank You @David for the answer of this question. Answer of this particular question is complete. I asked this this question to achieve some functionality. I am adding another question which is related to this. There I will write why I want to do this. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321643/can-we-override-the-standard-send-button-on-the-email    Thank You!

Comment: If your question is solved you may, at your option, accept an answer by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: I can't see the green check mark here.