# Can we override the standard "Send" button on the email?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, lightning, lightning-web-components

When user click on "Send" button at Case Email widget, a Pop/New UI should be visible where user can add/update the email body, cc address and to address. Can this be achievable using standard email widget?

[image]

Thank You!

Comment: As, it is a standard component I don't think we would be able to edit the send button functionality however, you can create a custom component in which the send button works as per your use case, this is a link for reference that you can use[ https://naveendhanaraj.wordpress.com/2018/05/28/email-lightning-component-to-send-and-receive-email-for-standard-and-custom-objects/ ]